# Using CSS grid to align content in a non responsive div

Tags: html, css, sass

My job is to supervise a junior developer, but I am mainly a javascript developer and my CSS skills are a bit basic. However, I spotted some things in his CSS code that seem unorthodox to me. He committed some CSS code similar to  the one I post here:

```
<div class="label-item">
    <div class="label-image-container">
        <img src="www.aphoto.com"/>
    </div>
    <div class="label-info">

        <span class="label-name">John</span>
        <span class="description">John is an elephant</span>
        <div>
            <span class="size">1000 kg</span>
            <span class="age">10 years old</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-button">
        <span> ... </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the sass:

```
.label-item {
  margin: .8rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4.4rem 1fr 1.8rem;
  grid-gap: 0 1rem;
  background-color: grey;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;

  .label-image-container {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;

    img {
      max-width: 50px;
      max-height: 50px;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      height: auto;
    }
  }

  .label-info {
    display: grid;
    position: relative;
    grid-gap: .3rem;

    .label-name {
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      line-height: 1.5rem;
      height: 1.4rem;
    }
    .description, .size, .age {
      font-size: 1rem;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
    }

    .age {
      margin-left: .8rem;
      float: right;
    }
}
  .more-button {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    grid-row-end: span 1;
  }
}
```

this is a codepen of this code:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QXadMP

My questions are:

a. Is grid positioning appropriate to alight and place elements inside a div that is not the main website container. I know that it works, but is this best practice?

b. Is nested grids considered to be best practice (.label-info inside .label item)?

c. Is using 'display: flex' appropriate to use just to align the content of a div in center?

Answer (score 2):

I think the CSS looks fine. To your questions

a.) It doesn't matter which container has the grid property. It's CSS. It's not semantic.

b.) I am not sure if it is considered a best practice, but a lot of people seem to use it this way. Just google CSS nested grid and you will get quite some articles and videos on that topic. For example [this](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example21/) and [this](https://www.quackit.com/css/grid/tutorial/create_a_nested_grid.cfm).

c.) Counter question: Why not? CSS doesn't add any semantic meaning to HTML. It's just for styling. So, IMHO as long as it works and is scalable/maintainable it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that, honestly, I don't consider best practices. In detail:

a) Using a grid seems not necessary there: such a structure could be realised with flex box only. It would have better compatibility.

b) I can't tell if nesting grids is considered a best practice either but this code does not get advantage of SASS in its nesting. Classes should have been written like this:

```
.label {
  &-item { }
  &-imageContainer { }
  &-info { }
  &-description { }
}
```

Moreover the div.label-info contains 2 spans and 1 div but, since all three are block-level elements, they should be divs.

c) Aligning with Flexbox is the right way but, as I said before, using Flexbox alone, without Grid, should have been a better practice.

I would also add that, since he's using Grid, all the floats are useless.